# (text + images ) files in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g.

My Java program gets some files having huge text contents + images. I want to Store Data (having text files with Images) in oracle. What is the best way to to insert and retrieve  the data from Oracle DB.

Should i use BLOBs or CLOBS?

Should i use XML data types?

Should i use Oracle Text datatype?

Please suggest the best practice.  Its pretty urgent.

Answer (score 0):

If the values may include binary data such as images, then `BLOB` is your best bet.

If the values only contain text, then `CLOB` should be fine.

If the values only contain XML, then either `CLOB` or `XMLType` may be used - you'll need to work out which is better for your situation - more info here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb01int.htm#ADXDB0120